# database mirroring with a witness db2

Tags: configuration, db2, backup, mirroring

I'm seeking for some guidance in performing mirroring with a witness in DB2. I've been searching for hours... I've found some information about split mirroring, but I've found nothing about how to configure a witness in DB2. Please help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, UNIX, and Windows platforms, the [HADR](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0011267.html) feature has been a popular approach for mirroring a DB2 database to an identical standby database since it was first introduced many years ago in v8.2. Starting with DB2 v10.1, HADR can mirror the primary database to [up to three standby databases](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0059994.html) instead of just one. HADR synchronizes the primary and secondary database(s) through transaction shipping over TCP/IP rather than a split mirror at the SAN layer.

In a DB2 HADR implementation (and in a DB2 pureScale cluster), the role of the witness is handled by a bundled and integrated installation of [IBM Tivoli System Automation for Multiplatforms](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0051289.html) (SA MP), which monitors a variety of resources inside the DB2 engine and throughout the operating system. The monitoring policies, heartbeat detection, and automated failover scripts are provided by IBM as part of the bundle, along with [db2haicu](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0051371.html), a configuration utility. SA MP software is running on each DB2 server involved with HADR, and is not isolated to a separate, dedicated witness server (as done in MS SQL Server).